# Relative merits of different open source natural language generators

Tags: nlp, text-mining

Does anyone know what (from your experience) is the best open source natural language generators (NLG) out there? What are the relative merits of each?

I'm looking to do sophisticated text summarization and would like to use theme extraction/semantic modeling in conjunction with NLG tools to create accurate, context-aware, and natural-sounding text summaries.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of open source NLG components, I'm most familiar with Mumble and FUF/SURGE. They've got both similarities and differences, so it's hard to say which is better...

[Mumble](https://code.google.com/p/sparser/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FMumble):

- written in Lisp
- [EPL license](http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html)
- based on tree-adjoining grammar
- focuses on linguistic message planning

[FUF/SURGE](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/surge/index.html):

- written in Lisp
- GPL license
- based on functional unification grammar
- focuses on syntactic realization

Since it sounds like you're interested in abstractive summarization (which is much harder than traditional extractive summarization), I'd recommend the following academic papers:

- [Text Generation for Abstractive Summarization](http://www.nist.gov/tac/publications/2010/participant.papers/Rali.proceedings.pdf)
- [Framework for Abstractive Summarization using Text-to-Text Generation](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W11-1608)
- [Towards a Framework for Abstractive Summarization of Multimodal Documents](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2000990) -- full disclosure: I'm the author of this one

Also, consider checking out this textbook to get started: [Building Natural Language Generation Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521620368)